# Sharing data between activities

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-activity

I want to get data from 2 activities( Activity and fragmentActivity) and I want to use this data in another class. Is there any way to share data among activities without using intent?

Comment: There are many ways like : Shared Preferences,Database and Static. Choose which more convenient for you.

Comment: Yes. There are so many options as suggested in above comment !!

Answer (score 1):

There is multiple ways to achieve that :

**Method 1:**

Use static class setter and getter method:

create static class and set values from first activity and get value from second activity

**Method 2:**

Post your values through the intent

**Method 3:**

Use database to store data from one activity and get data from other activity

**Method 4:**

Use Shared preference

Answer (score 0):

Use `SharedPreferences` like this:

```
//in the first activity where you want to save some values
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("com.myPackage.myApp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
prefs.edit().putString("name", "value").apply(); //the first parameter is the name with which you will fetch the value later, the cond one is the actual value

....
//fetch your data from another activity:
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("com.myPackage.myApp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String myVariable = prefs.getString("name", ""); //second parameter is a default value; you could use all primitive variable types like getString, getBoolean, getLong etc
```

P.S. if you use the `Sharedpreferences` in a Fragment, change the `this` with `getActivity()` and everything else is the same, just because the `this` doesn't mean the same in a Fragment as in an Activity